# How to make the PHP/HTML appear as a timer and Database entry issue?

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root"); 
 if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
 $db_select = mysql_select_db("Quiz",$db);
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
 }
?>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Quiz</title>

<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<form>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Questions`");
?>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
echo "<p class='question'>" . $row[1] . "</p>" . " <ul class='answers'>            
    <input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[2] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[2] . "</label><br/>   " . "<input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[3] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[3] . "</label>   <br/>" . "<input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[4] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[4] . "</label><br/>" ."<input type='radio' name='q1' value=" . $row[5] . "id='q1a'><label for='q1a'>" . $row[5] . "</label><br/>
</ul> ";        
}

mysql_free_result($result);  
?>
<input type="submit" formaction="index.php" formmethod="post">
</form>
<?php
$answer = $_POST[q1];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `User_Response`(`User_Response`) VALUES ('$answer')");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two problems in this code. 
One: I have to make only one question appear and then a timer starts for 30sec after which the question automatically shows the another one. I tried, i am successful in making an alert appear after 30sec in timer but not question.

Two: The User_Response Table had only increment in index but no values are there. I have made table with Serial (i.e. a mixture of longint and auto increment in MYSQL)

Guide me through my trouble.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the answer my friend, but mysql is deprecated. Use mysqli

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT..");
```

for example.

Comment: I herd that mysqli()  is for object oriented programming

Comment: Sorry! First time commenting, and noticed that this is under answers, and not comments. :/

Comment: I'm not too sure about that Ahmed, but mysql is definitely no longer in use.